# How to make an app change over midnight

Tags: android, c++, android-studio, development-environment

I am using Android studios 2.3.2 and I am trying to make an app. My app is supposed to be a daily checklist. The user will build their list and check them every day. This is why I want to reset the checklist every night.

I thought off using command that I found called hour to check if(hour == 0){resetChecklist();} or something like that. I am compleatly new to android studios so if you have better solutions I would love to hear them. I know some C++.

(Btw, I'm not sure I even understand how you could make a checklist.)

[image]

Comment: The image is just what I have made so far.

Comment: Save the date for each created item and if this date was yesterday don't display but delete it.

Comment: Hi and welcome to SO. It is recommended that you embed images in your post rather than provide links to external resources.

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to assume you will be using a local SQLite to be saving the lists that are created?

If so you can make this simple by adding a datetime column to the table, then when you query for the list query based on current date. So only items on that day will be returned.

Create a default for the date:

```
create table checklist(id int primary key, item text not null, completed boolean, dt datetime (default current_timestamp));
```

Query based on date:

```
 select * from checklist where dt between date('now', 'start of date' + '1 day')
```